# ubuntu-18.4 - multiple IP addresses via NetworkManager are failing

Tags: network-manager, ip

I'm on ubuntu-18.4 and I have 5 static IP's available to me. They are of the following form ...

```
a.b.c.34
a.b.c.35
a.b.c.36
a.b.c.37
a.b.c.38
```

I have set them up in the NetworkManager applet by specifying "Manual", and by trying to enter each of them in the IPV4 screen as follows:

```
Address     Netmask   Gateway
a.b.c.34         24   a.b.c.1
a.b.c.35         24   a.b.c.1
a.b.c.36         24   a.b.c.1
a.b.c.37         24   a.b.c.1
a.b.c.38         24   a.b.c.1
```

However, after saving the setup and then going back to the IPV4 screen, the "Gateway" values for the 2nd through 5th entries are blanked out, and after restarting my network, only the first IP address (a.b.c.34) is active.

What am I missing in order to get my machine to respond to all 5 IP addresses?

Thank you in advance.

**PS**: I know that the IP addresses are valid and active, because I previously was using them with my same machine that was running Ubuntu-16.x. Whatever I did on that machine, all IP's were working (but I forget the details of what I did). But after upgrading my machine to ubuntu-18.4 and trying to use NetworkManager, the 2nd through 5th IP's are not being recognized.

**Follow-up** ...

This is a laptop which is being used as my desktop and also as a server. And here is the requested info ...

```
# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
# ls -al /etc/systemd/network/
total 8
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 20  2018 ./
4 drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr 17 00:52 ../
```

**Further follow-up** ...

The connection is called "Hippo-Wired". I changed the high-order IP octets to "a.b.c" here, and I also anonymized the uuid, the Mac address, and the DNS entries. Note that there is only one IP address. The 2nd through 5th addresses in the applet are not showing. For some reason, the applet didn't accept them ...

```
# cat Hippo-Wired 
[connection]
id=Hippo-Wired
uuid=tttttttt-uuuu-uuuu-iiii-dddddddddddd
type=ethernet
autoconnect-priority=-999
permissions=
timestamp=1588347775

[ethernet]
mac-address=nn.nn.nn.nn.nn.nn
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]
address1=a.b.c.34/24,a.b.c.1
dns=sss.ttt.uuu.vvv;www.xxx.yyy.zzz;
dns-search=
method=manual

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto
```

Could it be that the applet will not allow more than one IP address with the same Gateway?

Comment: Is this a desktop or server installation? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `ls -al /etc/systemd/network/`.

Comment: Thank you very much. See "Follow-up", above.

Comment: Do `cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and look for the name of your connection profile... maybe called `Wired Connection`. `sudo cat Wired\ Connection` or similar, and let's take a look.

Comment: Thanks again. Check out "Further follow-up, above".

Comment: If you're using the NetworkManager GUI, ipv4 tab, and you clear out all of the address/mask/gateway entries, and just enter ONE address, then TAB, the mask will auto-populate... and does it say 24, or something else?

Comment: I put some unique, dummy gateways in place for the Gateway for each of the 2nd throiugh 5th entries, and then the applet accepted them. So it must be a "feature" of the NetworkManager applet to only allow one IP address per Gateway. I guess I could save those dummy entries and then manually edit the connection profile in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections to contain the correct Gateway addresses ... but I'd rather not rely on a hack like that.

Comment: Tabbing over the mask keeps it blank. It doesn't auto-populate

Comment: Remove all entries from NM GUI except for the first one. Then try manually editing the connection profile and just add ONE additional address/mask/gateway and see if it takes it. Remember to reconnect to that profile to check. Pretty soon we'll have to flip to chat...

Comment: It turns out that I can enter 255.255.255.0 instead of "24" for the netmask, and then it works!

Comment: Good! Let me write a quickie answer for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

When configuring the NetworkManager GUI for multiple IP addresses on the same connection profile...

Don't enter the Netmask as `24`, use `255.255.255.0`.

Like so...

```
Address     Netmask   Gateway
a.b.c.34  255.255.255.0   a.b.c.1
a.b.c.35  255.255.255.0   a.b.c.1
a.b.c.36  255.255.255.0   a.b.c.1
a.b.c.37  255.255.255.0   a.b.c.1
a.b.c.38  255.255.255.0   a.b.c.1
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! And after entering and saving 255.255.255.0, the gui shows each Netmask as "24". I got confused about that and that's what I manually entered.

Comment: @HippoMan Great news! It's working now. Carry on soldgier :-) I can't spell...